# Laptop keyboard turning off randomly

Tags: keyboard

I have been searching for a solution for a while and I have not been able to find one. My laptop keyboard tends to randomly stop working for a random time. There seems to be no rule whether or not will it work and how long will it be "offline" (it can be a few minutes or a few hours). Also restarting the laptop doesn't really do much. During the whole time USB keyboards work normally. I am using Toshiba Satellite P855-30F. Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: This sounds a lot like a failing cable connection or hardware issue... if moving or pressure does anything, that's one way to confirm it

Comment: Doubt it. If I restart my laptop the keyboard is working in grub. Also there are no such problems when I choose to boot windows, so the problem seems to be caused entirely by ubuntu.

Comment: I have a similar problem on a fresh 14.04 ... some key stop to work here and there ( control/alt/delete ... )